# Using same CGImageRef Buffer for different images?

Tags: performance, macos, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

I am looking for way to create CGImageRef buffer once and use it again for different images.

I my application is facing a performance hit as it creates a image and then draws it on context. This process is in a timer which fires every 1ms. I wonder if there is anything I could do to avoid calling 
CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapcontext); on every single tick.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one way you could theoretically do it:

1. Create an NSMutableData or CFMutableData.
2. Use its `mutableBytes`/`MutableBytePtr` as the backing buffer of the bitmap context.
3. [Create a CGDataProvider with the data object.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGDataProvider/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000952-CH1g-CJBIBEBE)
4. [Create a CGImage with that data provider](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreate), making sure to use all the same parameter values you created the bitmap context with.

However, I'm not sure that this is guaranteed to work. More specifically, I don't think that the CGImage is guaranteed not to copy, cache, and reuse any data that your data provider provided. If it ever does, you'll find your app showing a stale image (or even an image that is *partly* stale).

You might be better off simply holding on to the CGImage(s). If you generate the image based on some input, consider whether you might be able to cache resulting images by that input—for example, if you're drawing a number or two into the context, consider caching the CGImages in a dictionary or [NSCache](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSCache_Class/) keyed by the number(s) string. Of course, how feasible this is depends on how big the images are and how limited memory is; if this is on iOS, you'd probably be dropping items from that cache pretty quickly.

Also, doing anything every 1 ms will not actually be visible to the user. If you mean to show these images to the user, there's no way to do that 1000 times per second—even if you could do that in your application, the user simply cannot see that fast. As of Snow Leopard (and I think since Tiger, if not earlier), Mac OS X limits drawing to 60 frames per second; I think this is also true on iOS. What you should do at a reasonable interval—1/60th of a second being plenty reasonable—is set a view as needing display, and you should do this drawing/image generation only when the view is told to draw.

Comment: Heck, LCD panels don't refresh faster than 60 times per second--so even if the OS allowed it, you *still* wouldn't be able to see it.

Comment: @Jonathan Grynspan: That depends on the LCD, but yeah: Even the fastest TVs only go up to 240 Hz, which is less than a quarter of what the questioner is trying to do.

Comment: Ah, but those *only accept a 50Hz or 60Hz signal.* The extra frames drawn are interpolated from the source data. They can still only display at most 60 Hz worth of source data.

Comment: @Peter: I tried to use your technique with Dataprovider. I did worked well or may be I was not able to use it well. Though I have been benefited by your discussion on 60fps. Now application is at acceptable performance level.